# How to replace characters which are not alphanumeric in pyspark sql?

Tags: sql, pyspark

this is my code.

```
%spark.pyspark

jdbc_write(spark, spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        Global_Order_Number__c 
        , Infozeile__c
    FROM STAG.SF_CASE_TRANS
"""), JDBC_URLS['xyz_tera_utf8'], "DEV_STAG.SF_CASE", "abc", "1234")
```

I want to exclude every character in the Infozeile__c field which are not a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

Is their any function which is able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [regexp_replace()](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-regexp_replace-replace-string-value/) to the column in your query:

```
regexp_replace(Infozeile__c, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') as Infozeile__c
```

The regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is a *negated character class*, meaning any character not in the ranges given. The replacement is a blank, effectively deleting the matched character.

If you're expecting lots of characters to be replaced like this, it would be a bit more efficient to add a `+`, which means "one *or more*", so whole blocks of undesirable characters are removed at a time.

```
regexp_replace(Infozeile__c, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')
```

Comment: Is their a possibility to add ':' ',' ';' ?

Comment: @Hans sure, just add what you want to keep as single characters: `egexp_replace(Infozeile__c, '[^a-zA-Z0-9:,;]+', '')`. Ranges like `a-z` are just a convenience. Note: If you want to add a hyphen, put it last like `[^a-zA-Z0-9:,;-]+`, otherwise it will be treated as a range operator.